# Duplicating cursor movement and actions

Tags: windows-10, mouse, desktop

Is there a way to create one or more cursors a certain distance away from the main one, and have them behave exactly like the original? Imagine having 4 Virtual machines and by only controlling one, it would replicate your cursor behavior on the others: left click, right click and placement.

I have drawn an ugly example with paint — http://prntscr.com/kithjn

Comment: What technology are you using?

Comment: I'm on windows 10, I'm just looking for any way of achieving this